# Read access violation SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I am facing a read access violation error on SAS when running proc sql. 
the error is

```
The SAS task name is [SQL]

ERROR:  Read Access Violation SQL

Exception occurred at (2868651F)

Task Traceback
```

What could be the problem. 
The libname used is a usual libname and just accessing the data from a normal library.

```
libname xxx "location";
```

Comment: Hi. Have you seen this link?
http://support.sas.com/kb/44/180.html

Comment: Yes @Jonas but I am not using a META engine, I am using a normal SAS libname statement. just as I wrote in the description. .

Comment: Is the "location" pointing to a directory full of SAS datasets or some other RDBMS or... ?  Also suggest you show simple PROC SQL code that will cause this error, and curious if a proc print is able to read the data?

Comment: This is really a question for SAS tech support.  A RAV is usually a bug or unhandled exception in the underlying SAS code.  I suggest you submit a ticket on support.sas.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAS in a working environment and you are not the administrator, then you may have a meta engine that you are not aware of. Among other things, it can be used to set the access rights for various user groups. You may be in conflict with administrator defined user group permissions. See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrmeta/60739/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003162997.htm